# for a strong collection instance, is assign it to nil equals to release it and assign to nil?

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsmutablearray

So I have a strong collection variable x (of type NSMutableArray e.g.), when doing dealloc, if I only do x = nil, would it be the same effect as the following?

```
[x removeAllObjects]; 
[x release]; // not needed in ARC
x = nil;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Strictly speaking, the two are not identical. Setting a `strong` variable to `nil` will indeed release the object. However, an array will only `removeAllObjects` if it is getting destroyed. If another variable holds a strong reference to the array, it will stay alive and not remove the items it contains.

Comment: This is true, and worth being aware of. In almost all cases, however, the correct code is just `x=nil`. You should very seldom call `removeAllObjects` as part of releasing an object. If you're the only owner, then it's redundant. If you're not the only owner, then you probably shouldn't be clearing the array behind the others' back.

Answer (score 1):

Yes that is exactly what it would do. The way I like to think of it, is just like a nonatomic, retain property but it works for all variables, where each assign release the old value and assigns the new one. So assigning x to nil would release the old value. And just like without ARC you don't really need the removeAllObjects since destroying a container like NSArray will cause it to release all its references other objects.

To get a better idea of ARC I would recommend watching a 2011 WWDC video on it, which are available on developer.apple.com.

Another good resource to read is this http://longweekendmobile.com/2011/09/07/objc-automatic-reference-counting-in-xcode-explained/